# send html form with php can't solve

Tags: php, forms, send

I have big problem with sending easy html form with php.
My problem is when all fields are empty it still send message. 
I don't why this code still send empty form??

```
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="forma.php">
  <p>
    <label for="ime">Ime:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="prezime">Prezime:</label>
    <input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="email">e-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="poruka">Poruka:</label>
    <textarea name="poruka" cols="40" rows="10" id="poruka"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

My php code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$ime= $_POST['ime'];
$prezime= $_POST['prezime'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$poruka= $_POST['poruka'];

$email_from = 'neki@email.com';
$email_subject = "forma sa sajta";
$email_body = "Ime: $ime. \n". "Prezime: $prezime \n". "email: $email \n". "poruka: $poruka" ;
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
mail ($to, $email_subject, $email_body);

echo "Message is sent";

}

else {

echo "Message is not sent";

}

?>
```

So again, when i fill fields message is sent. It is ok, i received email.
But when i just click submit (without filling fields) it still send message to my email.

What is wrong with this code? I try everything i know, but without success.

Thank you.

Comment: you are only checking if submit is present in the POST array. Not that any of the fields are present. you would need to check that each field is not empty.

Comment: PHP isn't going to automatically value check your form, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: You could make an if else validation in it, and when it fails, make some fields red :) together with javascript you can make a very powerfull validation.

Comment: Bruh, I noticed you never accepted any answer on none of your questions. while we offer answers for free, we do like to get rewarded when correct. please accept the answer that solved it. do the same for your previous questions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only checking to see if "submit" is set.

Your if statement should read something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && all_other_fields_are_valid($_POST)){...}

function all_other_fields_are_valid($fields)
{
   //logic to decide what fields and values you require goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check all required field. only check submit it will attempt mailing:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']
        , $_POST['ime']
        , $_POST['prezime']
        , $_POST['email']
        , $_POST['poruka']))
```

Additionally you can validate from the client side using new HTML5 `required` attribute:

```
 <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" required />
```

This way you don't waste server resources for bad formed requests.

Answer (score 1):

Actually since they are sent as empty variables, they will still evaluate to true in isset(), even if there is no text in the input fields when they are submitted.

```
if($_POST['ime'] && $_POST['prezime'] && $_POST['email'] && $_POST['poruka']) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

As long as all of these have values and none of the values are 'false' or '0', this will evaluate to true only if somebody puts text in all of the input fields.

Answer (score 1):

This will check if all required POST vars are set, if they're empty and give an error if so:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['ime'], $_POST['prezime'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['poruka']))
{
    $error = "";
    if($_POST['ime'] == ""){
        $error .= "ima was empty!<br />";
    }
    if($_POST['prezime'] == ""){
        $error .= "prezime was empty!<br />";
    }
    if($_POST['email'] == ""){
        $error .= "email was empty!<br />";
    }
    if($_POST['poruka'] == ""){
        $error .= "poruka was empty!<br />";
    }

    if($error == ""){

        $ime= $_POST['ime'];
        $prezime= $_POST['prezime'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $poruka= $_POST['poruka'];

        $email_from = 'neki@email.com';
        $email_subject = "forma sa sajta";
        $email_body = "Ime: $ime. \n". "Prezime: $prezime \n". "email: $email \n". "poruka: $poruka" ;
        $to = "myemail@gmail.com";
        mail ($to, $email_subject, $email_body);

        echo "Message is sent";

    } else {

        echo $error;
    }
} else {

    echo "Message is not sent";

}

?>
```

Comment: take a look at the empty() function, it checks if the var exists and doesn't evaluate to false.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php